# Data binding work differently in .NET 4.0 from 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know why does data binding work differently in .NET 4.0?
I.e. in .NET 4.0 RelatedPropertyManager.GetItemProperties() returns properties from parent object's type, not from related one, as in following sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            ParentObject parent = new ParentObject();
            BindingManagerBase bindingManager =
                form.BindingContext[parent, "Nested"];
            Console.WriteLine("Has Code1 property: " + 
                (bindingManager.GetItemProperties()["Code1"] != null));
            Console.WriteLine("Has Code2 property: " + 
                (bindingManager.GetItemProperties()["Code2"] != null));

            // .NET 2.0:
            // Has Code1 property: False
            // Has Code2 property: True

            // .NET 4.0:
            // Has Code1 property: True
            // Has Code2 property: False

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ParentObject
    {
        public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
        public string Code1 { get; set; }
    }

    class NestedObject
    {
        public string Code2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have also asked question on Microsoft Connect, but there is no answer yet.

Comment: +1 Never think about it. Is it possible that so may changes had been introduces into C# language (anonymous delegates, anonymous structures, anonymous methods), that Reflection mechanism is also about to change?

Comment: Well, there are definitely breaking changes in .NET 4. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx

Comment: Issue on Microsoft Coinnect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688427/binding-to-a-nested-property-does-not-work-in-net-4-again#details

Answer (score 3):

The cause of issue is located in PropertyManager.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] list accessors), which is called from RelatedPropertyManager.
In .NET 4 listAccessors are ignored:

```
internal override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
{
    if (this.dataSource == null)
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection((PropertyDescriptor[]) null);
    else
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.dataSource);

}
```

In .NET 2.0 it was like this:

```
internal override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
{
    return ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(this.dataSource, listAccessors);
}
```

But I am not sure if it is a bug or intentional change in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It's not unheard of for things (even important things) to change between major release versions. The frameworks are different by two major versions in this scenario.

In addition, you may also note that a client with just .NET 4.0 Framework installed will not be able to run .NET 2.0 (or 3.x) apps which is in contrast to a client with 3.x installed being able to run 2.0 apps. .NET 4.0 is a big jump with lots of changes including the breaking changes mentioned by @Daniel.

Comment: Well, the reason behind the last thing you mention is that .NET 4 brought a new runtime, while .NET 3 did not.

Answer (score 1):

Such issues always raise the question: is it a bug or a feature? I can hardly imagine that this is intended behaviour because with .net 3.5 (2.0) you get the 4.0 results when you do `BindingManagerBase bindingManager = form.BindingContext[parent]` (without "Nested").

Why would `BindingContext` have an `Item[dataSource, dataMember]` property when the dataMember argument has no effect? Please keep us informed regarding the Microsoft issue.